# Why is boost::hana::experimental::types an experimental feature? what is tricky about a list of types?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I was looking into [Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) and I was surprised to see that it has a concept of a `type` (a "container of types" of sort, something like a one-element tuple with no actual value), but [types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1experimental_1_1types.html) (a sequence of `type`) is an experimental feature.

Does anyone know why? What is complicated about a list of types as opposed to a container of a single type?

Comment: What is the practical relevance of the `experimental` sub-`namespace`?

Comment: @Walter please make a new question instead of asking questions as comments to other unrelated questions.

Comment: In any case @Walter's is an easy question: from the user manual: "This directory contains experimental features that may or may not make it into the library at some point, but that were deemed useful enough to be made available to the public. Features in this subdirectory reside in the hana::experimental namespace. Also, do not expect these features to be stable; they may be moved, renamed, changed or removed between releases of the library. These features may also require additional external dependencies; each feature documents the additional dependencies it requires, if any."

Comment: You should really post this as an issue on Boost.Hana's github. I'd like to see `types` as a `hana::Sequence` but it wouldn't pass the laws as it won't hold any kind of value (like values with run-time state). I'm sure Louis has mulled this over and would make an exception if more people expressed that it would be useful to have it.

Comment: I was kind of hoping that Louis would see this question on stackoverflow because it's really more genuine curiosity than an issue. But *yes* it would be useful to have it: if the point of hana is expressing type computations as operations on heterogeneous containers, a `tuple` type that does not allocate memory would seem like an important piece of the puzzle

Comment: Answer to "a tuple type that does not allocate memory would seem like an important piece of the puzzle": A `hana::tuple` containing only empty objects will have a size of 1. The only problem is that the compile-time logic required to make this happen is non-trivial, which hurts compilation times.

Comment: Sorry the wording should have been "something like the tuple type, but without the object instantiations"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is basically what Jason said:

> I'd like to see types as a `hana::Sequence` but it wouldn't pass the laws as it won't hold any kind of value (like values with run-time state).

The "problem" is that a `hana::types` could not be made a `hana::Sequence`, because a `hana::Sequence` is supposed to be able to hold arbitrary things, not only types. While this may not seem like a big deal, it actually is. For example, we would also not be able to satisfy `hana::Monad`, since that requires `hana::flatten`, whose signature is `M<M<T>> -> M<T>` for an arbitrary `hana::Monad` `M`. Since `hana::types` can only hold types, you could not have e.g. `hana::types<hana::types<int, char>, hana::types<float, long>>` without special-casing the whole thing.

Whatever the solution is, I'd like to find a solution that does not break the conceptual integrity of Hana, while still allowing for a more compile-time efficient type list.

Comment: Thank you for answering and putting so much mental effort in getting things right and elegant. I'll take my time digesting the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. It's nice when things are elegant, but it's even better when they're both elegant and they allow us to do everything we want. There's still work to be done here, clearly.